# How to display static block anywhere in Magento 2

Tags: static, block, magento2

I have created block in Magento 2 admin panel. Block Identifier is "contact-us-info". I am using below code to display the block in my Magento site but not luck.

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="contact-us-info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="contact-us-info" xsi:type="string">contact-us-info</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

Please assist me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Phtml File:

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

in CMS Content:

```
{{block class="Magento\\Cms\\Block\\Block" block_id="block_identifier"}}
```